# netstat distinct values

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, netstat

how can I check netstats on ubuntu for a specific port? example

```
netstat -? grep: 80
```

but with a twist so it does this as well

it should show only distinct ip addresses but any duplicated ip addresses on a port should be assigned next to the ip and then order by the amount of duplicates

example:

```
client IP: 80.230.90.120  Port: 80  Occured: 4 times 
client IP: 70.122.30.25   Port: 80  Occured: 2 times 
client IP: 60.78.70.230   Port: 80  Occured: 1 times 
client IP: 40.42.90.220   Port: 80  Occured: 1 times
```

is this possible? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Port 80 on the remote machine or the local machine? Also, when you say "client IP" are you referring to the local machine as the client or the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

In it's current state, you question is unclear as to whether the local machine or the remote machine is the "client." Assuming you're looking for connections to port 80 on remote machines, the following should get you what you want. Just be sure the set `port=port-number-to-search` before running the commands or replace `$port` in the commands with the port you want to filter on.

**Simple one-liner:**

```
netstat -an | awk '{print $5}' | grep :$port | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

and the output looks like this:

```
      7 198.252.206.25:443
      4 74.125.28.189:443
      2 74.126.144.69:443
      2 65.55.252.167:443
      2 52.112.66.238:443
```

The number if front is the connection count for that IP on port 80.

**Pretty print one-liner:**

```
netstat -an | awk '{print $5}' | grep :$port | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | tr ':' ' ' | awk '{printf "client IP: %-15s  Port: %-5s  Occurred: %s time(s)\n", $2, $3, $1}'
```

and the output looks like this:

```
client IP: 198.252.206.25   Port: 443    Occurred: 9 time(s)
client IP: 74.126.144.69    Port: 443    Occurred: 2 time(s)
client IP: 74.125.28.189    Port: 443    Occurred: 2 time(s)
client IP: 34.210.168.7     Port: 443    Occurred: 2 time(s)
client IP: 216.58.217.195   Port: 443    Occurred: 2 time(s)
client IP: 192.0.73.2       Port: 443    Occurred: 2 time(s)
```

---

**Edit 2017-06-26**
Initially I wrote my commands such that they sort by IP. The OP said he/she was interested in sorting by frequency, so I made some changes to that effect. You may notice that the `sort` command is used before and after the `uniq` command. This is not a mistake. The first `sort` ensures that `uniq` command will be able to perform it's job. The second sort, is what actually does the sorting by frequency.

Comment: +1 . . . or perhaps all in awk, something like `awk -v p="$port" '{split($5,a,":")} a[2] == p {c[a[1]]++} END {for (i in c) printf "client IP: %-16s Port: %04d Occurred: %d times\n", i, p, c[i]}'`

Comment: Its exactly what I wanted, but the only thing you missed is that it should sort by occured, so 10 would be at top, but I tried the code you gave me and it did not work when I put custom port and removed $port, when I executed it, it didnt give any erros, just simply took me back to new line

Comment: @J.Doe, if you get nothing back, it likely means that there were no connections to the port specified on any remote machines. You can leave $port in place, so long as you set `port` like so `port=80`, making sure there are no spaces in that command. If you see nothing on port 80, try listing for 443 (https). I have edited my post to include an option for sorting by occurrence.

Comment: I found the issue, but I dont know how to address it, grep: $port actually shows the clients port that he is connecting with, so even if a client is on the website, it dont say port: 80, it gives like a random port, in my case port 44185, any idea how to address that? thanks alot btw for the codes and edits you make, so if I specify from grep: $port to grep : 44185, it works because then it shows the client port, but I would like to show for the listening port only, not interested in the clients port

Comment: Are you running this from the web server and trying to watch for connections coming into the web server? Could you possibly post your netstat and specify what exactly from that output you are trying to extract, adding it to your question?